# How to add title and description for product attributes in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes, seo, metadata

I need to add “meta data” + “robots meta” “schema” + “title” + “Permalink” + “Description” + “Canonical URL” + “Redirect” and “Schema” for WooCommerce attributes

I’m using the rankmath seo plugin and this plugin with some snippets can add something like that, called “Add SEO controls”
According to rankmath support

> Our SEO controls will only work for pages or posts registered in the
> database. The filter pages are dynamically generated and we cannot
> assign the SEO settings there so your only option for now is to use our
> filter code.

I have no idea how to add that to wordpress, does not matter if rankmath can or cannot, I need to have that options in my attributes.
I google it and found this:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/seo-controls-title-and-description-for-product-attributes/

If we archived the attributes, it will work like the page and post URLs, and I need query string url like general filters mysite.org/?brand=sony (if it possible , otherwise just add controls for attributes)

Thanks, everyone

Comment: Whats the point to have that data if you wont archive your attributes ?

Comment: Will target some keywords for SEO and its important to do that with a dynamic filter, not with pages or tags or categories